# Moq and Moq Contrib Versions

Tags: moq, moqcontrib

I can't find versions of moq and moq contrib that are alligned. I'm probably just having a google-fail.

**Details:**

Is there a version of moq.contrib that works with moq version 4.0.10827, the most recent from http://code.google.com/p/moq-contrib/downloads/list gives me an error:

CA0058 : The referenced assembly 'Moq, Version=4.0.812.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920' could not be found. This assembly is required for analysis and was referenced by: ...

Or is there a resource to download Moq 4.0.812.4 as http://code.google.com/p/moq/downloads/list only has 4.0.10827

Even installing both from nuget hasn't helped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems Moq Contrib has a new home: http://moqcontrib.codeplex.com/. There are no donwloads and not too much information about the current status of the project.

At least they know about this incompatibility issue: http://moqcontrib.codeplex.com/discussions/255319
but it seems since last April there is no fix for it nor a new relase of the lib.

You can try to fix yourself the dependecy and built the library from source.

Or

I've found this nuget package [Moq.Contrib.Indy](http://nuget.org/packages/Moq.Contrib.Indy)

> An independent implementation of the Moq.Contrib project, with
> up-to-date references to Moq and Autofac

I haven't tried it but maybe it worth a try...

Comment: Seems to work fine. It adds a couple of extra packages tho: Autofac, Autofac.CommonServiceLocator and CommonServiceLocator

Comment: Unfortunately Moq.Contrib.Indy has not moved up to the latest stable version of Moq, 4.1.1309.1617. In any case the solution needs to be not to take a hard dependency on the verison.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it in the following way.

1. Take the source from

http://code.google.com/p/moq-contrib/downloads/detail?name=Moq.Contrib-0.2-src.zip

- Then change the target framework to 4.0
- Add the moq 4.0 instead of existing moq
- Comment the "verify" and "VerifyAll" methods. There methods were virtual in 2.0 moq contrib
- Rename the methods calls
- MockFactory to MockRepository
       ExpectGet to SetupGet

There is a reference to Autofac in the project. I didnt try changing this reference to latest autofac.

Comment: I tried Nitin's Solution. But The definition for ContextSpecification was missing in Moq Contrib. I had to explicitly add it to the library. After that the steps worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a `bindingRedirect` in app.config:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Moq" publicKeyToken="69f491c39445e920" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0-4.2.1312.1622" newVersion="4.2.1312.1622" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

where `4.2.1312.1622` should be replaced with the latest Moq version.